# return goes to next line instead of leaving method

Tags: java, android

I have this code as part of my activity with pageviewer and fragments:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (GlobalVars.operator.equals("vodafone")) {
            return 5;
        }
        if (GlobalVars.operator.equals("kpn")) {
            return 4;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

When one of the conditions is done it goes to the line with return 5; or return 4;
Then it goes to return 0;
Why does not just leave the method with the return value from the if-then part?

Comment: Whats't the content of `GlobalVars.operator`? Have you tried `equalsIgnoreCase()` ?

Comment: are you sure that it is reaching return 5, or 4...

Comment: how do you know its stepping over return 5 and return 4? debugger or something? Also, try `.eqaulsIgnoreCase()` instead and see the result

Comment: Is `GlobalVars.operator` really of type `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java, a method can only have a *single* return value. This means that `getCount` cannot return both `4` or `5` and `0`.

As a debugging method, you might try displaying the return value of the function somehow (e.g. `System.out.println(getCount());`). If the displayed value is `0`, then neither of your criteria were fulfilled, and the method returned your "elsewhere" value.

I imagine that you're not performing the correct comparison on the data for this context. As some of the commenters mention, if you're receiving string data, you may want to compare ignoring case; further, if you're receiving the data from some input stream, you may want to make sure that it does not have leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: This is the most probable explanation. (Also, welcome to Stack Overflow.)

Comment: I change it by using an extra variable that gets the count number and then I return the variable contents. I noticed this it by stepping line by line through the code.